# Warning about "initializing pointer member 'height' with the stack address of parameter 'b' [-Wdangling-field]"

Tags: c++

The result was correct.
Can this warning be ignored and what errors might be raised and what would be better?

Here is my very simple code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Person{
    public:

    Person(int a,int b):age(a),height(&b){//Warning specific location here:height(&b)
        cout<<"initialize"<<endl;
        cout<<"height"<<*height<<endl;
    }
    
    Person(const Person &p){
        age = p.age;
        height = new int(*p.height);
    }
     
    int age;
    int *height;
};


void test02(){
    Person p1(10,150);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    test02();
    return 0;
}
```

Please forgive my poor level of code. If you have any ideas about the programming style or this issue, please feel free to share them.
Any help will be appreciated.

The idea behind this code is I'm trying to figure out how do I initialize a pointer variable.

The results of the code meet my expectations.

Comment: So, the answer is quite easy and clear, but I wonder why would you like to hold the height of a person in a pointer, instead of normal `int height`.

Comment: Using a pointer to save a person's height is meaningless, the original intention of this code is just to build a random class object test initialization problem.Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing the pointer to point to variable `b` but that is a parameter taken by value. The `b` object is destroyed after the function(constructor) exits, leaving the pointer dangling.

You want

```
Person(int a,int b):age(a),height(new int(b)){
        cout<<"initialize"<<endl;
        cout<<"height"<<*height<<endl;
    }
```

If you come from Java/C# background, C++ has very different value semantics - `new` should be only used if you need to manage lifetime manually and even then smart pointers are preferred. `T object;` is not some hidden pointer to heap, `=` means deep copy for `T`. If you need references, use `T&` or `T*` -  unless you ask for reference semantics, you do not get it.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the meaning of "T object; is not some hidden pointer to heap, = means deep copy for T",could you explain it in detail for me.

Comment: @frankli I mean that in other languages like C#, classes have reference semantics by default. If you have `Object a = new Object()` and then do `Object b = a`, you still have one object but two references to it. In C++ `Object b = a` always means copy operator, so if `Object` is e.g. `class Object{int x};`, then `Object a; Object b= a` creates two independent objects. If you want the reference semantics of C#, you have to use `Object*`, then `Object* b = a` copies the pointer  - shallow copy.

Answer (score 2):

Because in your constructor `int b` is local parameter, passed by copy, that ceases to exist when the constructor returns. This means that the address held by your `int *height;` will always (after your object construction) point to incorrect block of memory and any attempt to dereference it will result in Undefined Behaviour.